# Does Germany have a comprehensive occupational classification?

Tags: germany

For example, Canada has National Occupational Classification, and Australia and New Zealand have the Australian and New Zealand Standard Classification of Occupations (ANZSCO).

So, does Germany have a comprehensive occupational classification like them?

Answer (score 3):

Germany has a classification known as

> Klassifikation der Berufe 2010 (KldB 2010)

Which is produced by the Bundesagentur für Arbeit (German Federal employment agency).  Previously there were two standards used in Germany, but since 2010 then this has been combined into this single standard.

This document in English http://doku.iab.de/fdz/reporte/2013/MR_08-13_EN.pdf  provides more detailed information.

Or if preferred a simplified version in German:
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klassifikation_der_Berufe_2010

**A basic overview/introduction**

There are 5 levels which are denoted by the length of the number used to define them.

- Level 1  = 10 Occupational Areas (1-digit code)
- Level 2 = 37 Occupational Main-Groups (2-digit code)
- Level 3 = 144 Occupational Groups (3-digit code)
- Level 4 = 700 Occupational Sub-Groups (4-digit code)
- Level 5 = 1,286 Occupational Types (5-digit code)

Which each level then going into more and more detail.

The first level, (1 digit code) comprises the following occupational areas:

- 1 - Agriculture, forestry, animal husbandry and horticulture
- 2 - Raw material extraction, production and manufacturing
- 3 - Construction, architecture, surveying and building technology
- 4 - Science, geography and computer science
- 5 - Traffic, logistics, protection and security
- 6 - Commercial services, goods trading, sales, hotel and tourism
- 7 - Business organization, accounting, law and administration
- 8 - Health, social issues, teaching and education
- 9 - Linguistics, literature, humanities, social and economic sciences, media, art, culture and design
- 0 - Military

Until you end up with a level such as

- 12 - Occupations in horticulture and floristics

  - 121 - Horticulture
  - 1210 - Occupations in horticulture (without specialisation)
  - 12103 - Complex specialist activities, e.g. landscape technician

(All details taken from the sources above)

Comment: _Klassifikation der Berufe (KldB)_ is still in use by the Federal Employment Agency, but there is a _general_ intent to _eventually_ adopt the multilingual [ESCO taxonomy](https://ESCO.EC.Europa.eu/en) (European Skills, Competences, qualifications and Occupations).